# Abroad good credit as minor supplement for U.S.-based credit bureaus and their algorithms?

Tags: united-states, credit, credit-history, singapore

So I have good credit in the U.S. But I have impeccable credit in Singapore where I lived for past four years.

Is there any chance I could convince one of the credit bureaus in the U.S. to consider my good standing abroad, maybe to a minor extent but important nonetheless, as evidence of my consistency in paying large debts on time?

Answer (score 2):

Just reporting this yourself will almost surely not work. If you can get your creditors in Singapore to report to the U.S. credit agencies directly, that might work.

I've seen this done to improve credit ratings in the case of U.S. loan applicants with U.S. creditors not appearing on the credit report.  I'm not sure if this is still possible at all, however, or if it will work internationally.  In the cases that I saw it done, the loan originator (an employee of the bank) requested that the information be added to the credit report by sending related information to the credit rating agencies.  This person is paid for having loans approved, so their motivation is to have their applicants look at good as possible.  My experience with this is dated, however, and so this might not be allowed at all under current regulations.

Comment: Thank you to all those who responded. It means a lot. this is the first time I have ever posted a question on the internet and this has really proven to me just how useful forums like these can be!

Answer (score 1):

Many people have tried, but it is rather futile. The agencies will not report something not reported directly to them by creditors.

Instead, you may want to try and convince the lenders directly. That has worked, occasionally, and some lenders even have very well defined processes for that. For example, [American Express Global Transfer](https://www.americanexpress.com/global-card-transfers/).